# Truncate partition vs Drop partition (performace wise) which one is efficient and better to use?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

How do these commands differ performance wise

```sql
ALTER TABLE t1 DROP PARTITION p1;
```

and

```sql
ALTER TABLE t1 TRUNCATE PARTITION p1;
```

I have got one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56244720/what-is-the-difference-between-mysql-drop-partition-and-truncate-partition) with the same question but it only addresses the output of the commands and not the efficiency like whether it'll be like deleting the rows one by one or at once all will be deleted.
NOTE: Considering large amount of data say millions of rows in the partition.

Comment: Please explain how/why you are using partitioning.  Cf: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: The table has got millions of rows per day and I am looking to remove the rows that are a month old.

Comment: Why even consider `TRUNCATE`, if you will then `DROP` the partition?  Use `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))` and `DROP` + `REORGANIZE` daily.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping a partition should be a tiny bit faster, though you'll struggle to measure it. If I remember correctly, TRUNCATE is implemented as a DROP+CREATE.

Answer (score 1):

***I don't know if that answers your question:***

**TRUNCATE** and **DROP** work exactly the same and perform equally fast but do different things.

**TRUNCATE**: Deletes all rows from a table without recording individual row deletions.

**DROP**: Drops one or more table definitions and all data, indexes, triggers, constraints and permission specifications for those tables.

**TRUNCATE**, **DROP** are both a minimal logging operation. This means they work exactly the same way. Instead of deleting individual rows, it marks the relevant data pages as unallocated and additionally marks the table's metadata as deleted.

**TRUNCATE** and **DROP** are almost identical in terms of behavior and speed. And anyway, if you don't need the table structure at all, use **DROP**.

Comment: Caveat:  MySQL 8.0, with its "data dictionary" may not have "minimal logging".  (I don't yet know the details.)