# Scheduled truncation of MySQL Partitions

Tags: mysql, truncate, partition

I have a MySQL (version 5.6) database with an audit table to store all transactions related to the inventory. I have the table partitioned based on the month of the transaction date of the event. So the table looks like this.

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13726377500 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ( month(creationDate))
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (4) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (6) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (7) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (8) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (9) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (10) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (11) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (12) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (13) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */ |
```

My use case is that I want to truncate the older partitions every month (on the date of 15th since I need the last 15 days transactions). Is there a way to achieve this by creating an event? Can somebody help me with the same?

Comment: So you want to drop a partition each month?

Comment: No no, I want to truncate the previous months' partition on the 15th of this month. Not drop since I want to create the partition structure intact.

Comment: I don't really  see the point of the partitions then !?!

Comment: If I want to delete the old data, having partitions definitely helps because truncate doesn't take lock on the entire table for the duration. But if I were to run a delete query on the table then it would require a lock and downtime.

Comment: Like Rick at this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56244720/what-is-the-difference-between-mysql-drop-partition-and-truncate-partition] I'm struggling to see why preserving the structure matters. But whatever floats your boat, I guess. As an aside, note that DROP and REORGANIZE is much faster than DELETE

Comment: I understand that DROP and REORGANIZE (similar to TRUNCATE in terms of the time taken) is much faster than DELETE, which is exactly why I want to be able to TRUNCATE.


About the maintaining structure part, Now I have created a table with 12 partitions based on month and don't want to manually do something about creating new partitions. So if I maintain the structure, I don't have to worry after a year about the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I can achieve it by creating an event using statements and variables.

```
delimiter |
//Creating an event 
Create event scheduledTruncate
    // this is used to indicate that it's a recurring event
    on schedule  every 30 day 
    // starting time. end time can also be provided. If nothing is provided, then it's null
    starts '2021-03-15 20:24:50'
    DO
      BEGIN
      //Essentially identifying the last months partition. -2 since we start indexing from p0.
      SET @var_par = CONCAT('p',MONTH(CURDATE()) - 2);
      // The initial months where in january, we have to truncate the december table
      IF MONTH(CURDATE()) < 2
        SET @var_par = CONCAT('p',MONTH(CURDATE()) + 10);
      // creating a mysql statement using the above created variables
      SET @s = CONCAT('alter table xyz truncate partition ', @var_par);
      PREPARE STATEMENT from @s;
      //executing the statement
      EXECUTE STATEMENT;
      END |

delimiter ;
```